# Ignore Run-time Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I want to import  some data cell from Workbook A to WorkBook B. what i do is I used application.inputbbox to put the value. the problem is when i click cancel on the inputbox .

> the Run-time Error 1004 occur on this line.`Set xRng1 =
>   .Range(.Cells(addStartRow, 2), .Cells(addEndRow, 12))`

my question is how can i click cancel the inputbox without the error popup. what i know is, it can be done by put `on error` statement. i dont know where to put the statement

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub importbr_Click()


Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xAddWb As Workbook
Dim xRng1 As Range
Dim xRng2 As Range
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Dim xTitleId As String
    Dim addStartRow As Integer
    Dim addEndRow As Integer
    Dim pastevalue As Integer


xTitleId = "Select BR file"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .InitialFileName = "C:\New"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)

        Set xAddWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

        addStartRow = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Type Start row", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="200", Type:=1)
            addEndRow = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Type End row", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="500", Type:=1)
            With xAddWb.Sheets(1) 'change the index as needed
                Set xRng1 = .Range(.Cells(addStartRow, 2), .Cells(addEndRow, 12))


            End With

        xWb.Activate
        Set xRng2 = Cells(5, 1)



        xRng1.Copy xRng2


        xAddWb.Close False
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just exit if both row values are not numeric

Comment: OK then numeric (whole number!) and non-zero ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Tim Williams stated in the comments, all you need to do is handle what happens to the variables when you click cancel on the `Input Box`

Add this to your code,

```
If addStartRow > 0 And addEndRow > 0 Then
        Set xRng1 = .Range(.Cells(addStartRow, 2), .Cells(addEndRow, 12))
Else
        GoTo eExit
End If
```

And the full code,

```
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xAddWb As Workbook
Dim xRng1 As Range
Dim xRng2 As Range
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Dim xTitleId As String
    Dim addStartRow As Integer
    Dim addEndRow As Integer
    Dim pastevalue As Integer


xTitleId = "Select BR file"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .InitialFileName = "C:\New"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
    Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)

    Set xAddWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    addStartRow = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Type Start row", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="200", Type:=1)
        addEndRow = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Type End row", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="500", Type:=1)
        If addStartRow > 0 And addEndRow > 0 Then
            With xAddWb.Sheets(1) 'change the index as needed
               Set xRng1 = .Range(.Cells(addStartRow, 2), .Cells(addEndRow, 12))
            End With
            xWb.Activate
            Set xRng2 = Cells(5, 1)

            xRng1.Copy xRng2
        End If
    xAddWb.Close False
End If

End With
```